# This question is asked on Dec 2014, 4 months ago? (Today is May 2015)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, dates, time, date-format

The question is [Does your university name matter?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/34899/14341) in Academia.

[image: image description]

In my calculate, it's almost 5 months, so when rounding it, should the number be rounded to 5?

Suggest feature/discussion: instead of rounding down, should we round it to the closest number?

Comment: I think rounding is hard numbers, so until it's been five full months, it will not round up. So, 4.9 rounds to 4, not to 5.